# How to count data rows in jqgrid and prevent display if a threshold is exceeded

Tags: jquery

I need to count the number of rows of data returned to JQgrid before they are displayed and if an upper limit is exceeded display a dialog to the user like "maximum number of search results exceeded.  Please refine search criteria".  Does anyone know how to do this?  One idea I have is that since I have this definition:
 jsonReader : {
    root: "rows",
    page: function(obj) { return 1; },
    total: function(obj) { return (obj.rows.length/numberOfRowsPerPage); },
    records: function(obj) { return obj.rows.length; },
    repeatitems: false,
    cell: "cell",
    id: "id",
    userdata: "userData"
 }

I might be able to make use of the value in 'records' but I don't know if this is a dead end or not or how or where to get that value from.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you shouldn't retrieve all data from the server and do this check on the client. Have you considered using server-side pagination on your grid?

If you insist on doing this on the client, you could use the [`beforeProcessing`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) event like so:

```
beforeProcessing: function (data, xhr, status) {
    if (data.records.length > 999) {  // Replace with your limit
        alert("Some message!");
    }
}
```